# Global Temporary table delete operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, temp-tables

How to check if the global Temporary table exists in SQL server, if yes then delete that global temporary table?

I am trying to execute this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('##Table', 'U') IS NOT NULL  
  DROP TABLE ##Table
```

...but it is not working.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To check the presence of temp table and delete it

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Table' , 'U') IS NOT NULL
   drop TABLE ##Table
```

Comment: what is 'U' for?

Answer (score 5):

You can detect temp table presence with

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##Table', 'U') IS NOT NULL
```

and, surprisingly to me, you can drop it from any connection with

```
DROP TABLE ##Table
```

However, I can't help but think that doing so would be a bad idea, since presumably the connection/user who created it might still be using it...

Answer (score 1):

look in this View to see if the table exists:

```
[tempdb].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]
```